# Why after login keycloak display "Cookie not found. Please make sure cookies are enabled in your browser."

Tags: javascript, cookies, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

After login from keycloak login page to my website. it display "Cookie not found. Please make sure cookies are enabled in your browser.". check my cookie is enable to the browser.

Expect the display my dashboard after login from the keycloak default login page. not display message. I already try allow cookie to the browser already. javascript also enable the cookie.

```
<script>
  var keycloakConfig = {
    realm: "xxx",
    url: "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/auth",
    clientId: "xxx",
  };
  var keycloak = Keycloak(keycloakConfig);
</script>
<script>
  keycloak.init({ onLoad: "login-required" }).success(function (authenticated) {
    // This function is called after successful authentication
    if (authenticated) {
      debugger;
      // User is authenticated, you can proceed with your application logic here
    } else {
      // User is not authenticated
      // You can choose to show a login button or take other actions
      debugger;
    }
  });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you running this code on a "HTTP"/"HTTPS" protocol, or perhaps a local one?

Comment: local one for html. keycloak server is https

Comment: And I guess you're using Chrome? Or what other browser? I shall I don't know the keycloak server and how it works, but if it uses JS cookies, JS Cookies cannot be saved on local protocols in most browsers, although you might check whether I'm right or not via running the code in Firefox; Firefox allows local JS Cookies, I'll be happy to be informed about it.

Comment: i using firefox, chrome and edge

Comment: Then I'm not capable of answering your question I fear. Good luck!

Comment: C# side no issue

Comment: solved after add my localhost domain to Content-Security-Policy

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the Hostname in the keycloak.conf file matches the URL you are using to access the Keycloak server. If it doesn't match, please add the correct URL, then run 'kc.sh build,' restart the Keycloak service, and attempt to log in again.